# Lenovo G550 Keyboard Removal

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair

I have a Lenovo G550 Notebook given by an university to students.

The "M" key on keyboard flipped out due to poor build quality. Tried hard to replace it, bought new single key, however I've only failed because the keyboard electronics are also turned out to be damaged.

I have found a replacement keyboard from a local site, verified that it has the correct number and bought it. For the curious, it is around $50 here in Turkey.

I can't find a way to remove keyboard from Lenovo G550.

At first I thought it would be easy like ThinkPad's, but even with ALL the screws out (including the ones from CPU fan!) keyboard never ever moved a bit. I'm about to break much more keys while trying to move it. So I stopped.

Google searches only lead to ThinkPad models, (unscrew from RAM compartment, keyboard moves) but they DO NOT apply to this model.

I checked http://www.lenovoservicetraining.com/ion/ which doesn't have any information about G550.

I tried to remove Multimedia Panel (the plastic panel which has Power, Recovery, Mute, Volume Up/Down buttons) but the panel itself is incredibly tight and I'm afraid to break it.

How do we remove/replace keyboard on Lenovo G550?

I'm including some photos of the model with descriptions.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/5ccm2]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's what I found by watching every other video in Lenovo support training site.

http://www.lenovoservicetraining.com/ion/N500/index.html

This model does not have many similarities with Lenovo G550 but the Multimedia Panel (Keyboard Cover) looks same.

So I guess I have to use more force while disassembling it.

Here are the steps to remove / replace Lenovo G550 Keyboard

1. Watch Keyboard Cover Removal video in http://www.lenovoservicetraining.com/ion/N500/index.html
2. Turn laptop backwards
3. Pull the battery out
4. Find 4 screws on battery compartment. Remove them.
5. Turn laptop forward and open the lid.
6. Using force and a flat screwdriver, carefully remove Multimedia Panel
7. Unscrew 4 keyboard holder screws
8. Rotate keyboard and carefully disconnect ribbon cable
9. Reverse the process

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJzUYSikdRI as there is a complete instruction there. However, I suggest to use a plastic spudger (or a plastic knife from a camping set) to remove the cover above the keyboard after removing the screws.

Answer (score 0):

This site purports to have a video of the process.  Not having one I cannot tell if this is the correct model.  Worth a look [G550 Keyboard video](http://www.laptopkeyboard.com/Guides.php/Lenovo/G%20Series/G550/L15)

Comment: No useful information. The laptop shown on video is a Sony VAIO, which in no way related to Lenovo G550.